# Why is one query faster than the other?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    spentits.*,
    username,
    (SELECT count(*) from likes where likes.spentit_id = spentits.id) as like_count,
    (SELECT count(*) from comments where comments.spentit_id = spentits.id) as comment_count,
    (SELECT count(*) from wishlist_items where wishlist_items.spentit_id = spentits.id) as wishlist_count,
    (case when likes.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as is_liked_by_me,
    (case when wishlist_items.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as is_wishlisted_by_me
FROM spentits
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = spentits.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.user_id = 9 AND likes.spentit_id = spentits.id
LEFT JOIN wishlist_items ON wishlist_items.user_id = 9 AND wishlist_items.spentit_id = spentits.id
WHERE spentits.user_id IN
    (SELECT follows.following_id
     FROM follows
     WHERE follows.follower_id = 9)
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 15;
```

This takes on average `43ms` to execute. Now another query (below), which doesn't have the where clause, not to mention a second SELECT sub query performs 5x slower (`240ms`)!

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    spentits.*,
    username,
    (SELECT count(*) from likes where likes.spentit_id = spentits.id) as like_count,
    (SELECT count(*) from comments where comments.spentit_id = spentits.id) as comment_count,
    (SELECT count(*) from wishlist_items where wishlist_items.spentit_id = spentits.id) as wishlist_count,
    (case when likes.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as is_liked_by_me,
    (case when wishlist_items.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as is_wishlisted_by_me
FROM spentits
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = spentits.user_id
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.user_id = 9 AND likes.spentit_id = spentits.id
LEFT JOIN wishlist_items ON wishlist_items.user_id = 9 AND wishlist_items.spentit_id = spentits.id
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 15;
```

Why? Shouldn't the second query be much much faster, as there's no condition, no second query. All the database needs to do is select last 15 records, compare to the first one where it needs to SCAN every single record AFTER performing a sub query and check if the ids are contained in it. I am just really confused a query that should performnce much faster is actually perofming 5x slower.

Comment: There are executions path that are related to statistics and metadata, do a `explain plan` for both. Filtering by an id might perform an skip on tables that does not have rows, when you do not filter by that id the rows are proyected.

Comment: is it not because with the first one having a where clause it is bringing back less rows?

Comment: @anna both of them have LIMIT 15

Comment: The first version is limiting the number of rows to a much smaller number so the `order by` is doing much less work.

Comment: it should be the order by working on different amounts of rows

Comment: @GordonLinoff removing the ORDER makes much more sense. Now, second now takes 1.5ms, first one takes 2.7 seconds.

Comment: Could the joins be pre-empted by the WHERE criteria, only performed for relevant rows, or is the optimizer not that smart?

Comment: @Goat_CO . . . The answer is "maybe".  The role of the query optimizer is to figure out the best way to perform the query.  Sometimes a `where` will be performed after the `from` conditions, sometimes during.  But, note that `in` with a subquery is just another type of `join`, so it is probably done along with all the other joins.

Answer (score 1):

There are executions path that are related to statistics and metadata, do a `explain plan` for both and take a look at the execution path.

Besides, Filtering by an id might perform an skip on tables that does not have matching rows, when you do not filter by that id the rows are projected.